# Updating customfield XrayTest on JIRA : Error instantiating bean. Field(s) tests -\\u003e customFields -\\u003e name do not follow the correct format

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-xray

Hello i have been developing a python script to update Xray test on Jira using rest API `BaseUrl/rest/raven/2.0/api/import/execution`

however I have been receiving this error `Error instantiating bean. Field(s) tests -\\u003e customFields -\\u003e name do not follow the correct format.` when i run the python script

```
url = "BaseUrl/rest/raven/2.0/api/import/execution"
personal_access_token = "******"

# Test execution JSON payload
test_execution = {
    "testExecutionKey": "T4SV-T561",
    "info": {
        "revision": "1.0.42134",
        "testEnvironments": [
        "windows",
        "Linux"
    ]
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "testKey": "T4SV-T415",
            "status": "PASS",
            'executedBy':'*****@**.com',
            "comment": "Test passed successfully",
            "start": "2023-09-07T11:47:35+01:00",
            "finish": "2023-09-07T11:50:56+01:00",
            "customFields": [
                {
                 "id": 1,
                 "name": "Name1",
                 "value": "[https://www.#.net"
                 },
                {
                 "id": 2,
                 "name": "Name2",
                 "value": "https://www.#.net"
                }]            
        }
    ]
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + personal_access_token}
# Send the POST request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(test_execution),verify=False)
```

the POST request works fine with no errors if I remove the `customfield` part from the JSON so I don't know in which format I should add the custom field because i got it exactly like that format from `BaseURL/rest/raven/2.0/api/project/{ID}/settings/customfields/testruns`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take out the `name` attribute from the `customFields` object. You need to use the `id` instead, along with the `value`.

See the [following page](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Import+Execution+Results#ImportExecutionResults-%22customFields%22object-storetestruncustomfields) for more info on the customFields object. That page also has the JSON schema of the Xray JSON format.

Your script would become something like:

```py
url = "BaseUrl/rest/raven/2.0/api/import/execution"
personal_access_token = "******"

# Test execution JSON payload
test_execution = {
    "testExecutionKey": "T4SV-T561",
    "info": {
        "revision": "1.0.42134",
        "testEnvironments": [
        "windows",
        "Linux"
    ]
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "testKey": "T4SV-T415",
            "status": "PASS",
            'executedBy':'*****@**.com',
            "comment": "Test passed successfully",
            "start": "2023-09-07T11:47:35+01:00",
            "finish": "2023-09-07T11:50:56+01:00",
            "customFields": [
                {
                 "id": 1,
                 "value": "[https://www.#.net"
                 },
                {
                 "id": 2,
                 "value": "https://www.#.net"
                }]            
        }
    ]
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json",'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + personal_access_token}
# Send the POST request
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(test_execution),verify=False)
```